# ¿Como agregar un contador cada vez que se ejecute una función en JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jq

Tengo la siguiente función, esta función se realiza cada vez que de un clic en unas tarjetas, lo que requiero hacer es que cada vez que se ejecute esta función, la variable contador se sume 1, es decir: Se ejecuta por primera vez la función y el restado es 1, se ejecuta la segunda entonces el valor de contador es 2 y así sucesivamente.

```
    function deseleccionar(selecciones) {
        var contador = 0;
          contador;
          alert(contador);

        setTimeout(() => {
            let trasera1 = document.getElementById("trasera" + selecciones[0])
            let trasera2 = document.getElementById("trasera" + selecciones[1])
        
        
            if (trasera1.innerHTML != trasera2.innerHTML) {
                let tarjeta1 = document.getElementById("tarjeta" + selecciones[0])
                let tarjeta2 = document.getElementById("tarjeta" + selecciones[1])
                tarjeta1.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)"
                tarjeta2.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)"
            }else{
                
                trasera1.style.background = "plum"
                trasera2.style.background = "plum"
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Sin embargo me suma solamente una vez, es decir el resultado que obtengo es 1. despues sigue siendo 1, etc .¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo? Saludos!

Comment: declara la variable `contador` fuera de la función y aumenta su valor dentro de la función.

Comment: Gracias, de mucha ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Tal como menciona @Christian, basta con declarar la variable fuera de la función e incrementarla dentro de la misma. Luego con el resultado puedes mostrarlo en consola, en un `alert` o pasarla a un elemento del DOM.

Es de aclarar que el contador se reiniciará tan pronto como se recargue la página.

```js
var contador = 0;

function deseleccionar() {
  contador++;
  console.log('contador: ' + contador);
  alert('contador: ' + contador);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="deseleccionar()">Ejecutar</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudo! en complementarlo